# Reading file in parallel from multiple processes

Tags: parallel-processing, filesystems

I'm running multiple processes in parallel and each of these processes read the same file in parallel. It looks like some of the processes see a corrupted version of the file if I increase the number of processes to > 15 or so. What is the recommended way of handling such a scenario?

More details:
The file being read in parallel is actually a perl script. The multiple jobs are python processes, and each of them launch this perl script independently with different input parameters. When the number of jobs is increased, some of these jobs give errors that the perl script has invalid syntax (which is not true). Hence, I suspect that some of these jobs read in corrupted versions of the perl script.

I'm running all of this on a 32core machine.

Comment: " It looks like some of the processes see a corrupted version of the file" - 2 things: (1) you probably have a bug in your synchronisation logic. (2) its highly unlikely reading a file with multiple processes will make it any faster, it will probably be slower.

Comment: There is no synchronization logic whatsoever. As I said, this file is a perl script which is being launched in parallel. So yes, it will be faster because each perl process is working on an independent data set

Comment: "There is no synchronization logic whatsoever" - There's your problem! (I figured as much). Read what I said again. I did not say that your presumably complex processing will not be faster, I said " its highly unlikely READING a file with multiple processes will make it any faster (i.e. the file read part)"

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this issue of reading a file in parallel. Could you throw more light on it? Why is it an issue only if the number of parallel reads is high (i.e. 10+)?

Answer (score -1):

If any process is also writing to the file, then  you need to enforce some synchronization, for example with a global named mutex.

If there is no asynchronous writing going on, I would not expect to see corruption during the reads.  Are you opening the files with "r" access?  If you're still encountering troubles, it might be worth experimenting with reducing read buffer size.  Or call out to a native win32 API for the file access.

Good luck!

Comment: The files are not being written to. The file is myScript.pl and is being called as 'perl myScript.pl' within each process. There are around 20 such processes. It's not being 'read' in the sense that you are referring to